# startActivity in onPause() not working after opening new app

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, onpause, start-activity

I Start a second activity when my first activity is paused.

*FirstActivity.java*

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
}
```

When I press on the homescreen button, SecondActivity will start but with a delay. In this delay, there is enough time to open a new app (like messenger for instance). However, when I open a new app, SecondActivity will not start anymore (it won't even call the onCreate method of SecondActivity).

How can i still start SecondActivity even when I open a new app?

Comment: When you press back from your opened new app, do you go to your SecondActivity or home screen? And why do you want to open SecondActivity from onPause?

Comment: When I press back, I go to my SecondActivity. I want to open SecondActivity from onPause as a "lockscreen".

Comment: please state what do u want to accomplish exactly

Comment: I want to start SecondActivity after pressing on the homescreen and opening a new app. Until now, SecondActivity starts only if I don't open a new app.

Comment: @BernSimpson I have same requirement. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() method and start new activity from there, instead of adding your code into onPause().

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I want to start my SecondActivity whenever i leave my FirstActivity. Leaving FirstActivity can not only be done by a back press, but can also be done by pressing on the homescreen button. Therefore, this problem wont be solved by overriding the onBackPressed() method and starting the new activity from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, if you would like to launch the new activity I would go with onStop, instead of onPause. 
Start the new activity with the flag of: singleInstance

```
<activity ..
  android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

Please use onStop() in the second activity and call finish() there. so you killing the 2nd activity instance, when leaving the app. You can restart it easily.

Comment: Do you mean I need to call finish() in the onStop() of SecondActivity? Because that doesn't work unfortunately.